# MacBook Pro display turns black when unplugging external HDMI monitor

Tags: macos, display

Whenever I unplug my HDMI monitor, my MacBook Pro (mid-2010) display turns black. This persists through reboots. Is there a way to reset the display settings for my laptop?

I've tried resetting the display cache (option-command-p-r when rebooting), without success.

I am running Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.3.

Comment: What kind of external monitor are you using? VGA, DVI, DisplayPort, HDMI, Thunderbolt, USB 3?

Comment: it's an HDMI based monitor

Comment: Does it flash black for a second or for an extended period of time? It's normal for the internal display to flash for a second after unplugging external. Additionally, you can attempt to [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: it turns immediately black, and stays black. rebooting the computer and/or hard resetting the vram (as listed above) don't make a difference (ie, unplug external monitor, reboot, laptop screen shows apple logo but immediately turns black afterwards)

Comment: The same thing started happening to me on my late 2013 macbook pro retina, with Sierra 10.12.2.